# Drupal 7 - moving code away from template.php into custom module

Tags: drupal-7, preprocessor, drupal-modules

I have a rather large template.php file and was looking at a better way to organise it. The main culprit is theme_preprocess_node() which has lots of code.

Can someone suggest a good way to keep this tidy and readable? Can I create custom functions in template.php.

Alternatively can this be split up into custom modules? And if so how can I get access to the $vars or $variables (page variables) that I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced this kind of code mess up in theme esp in template.php. My Idea Goes like this,

- Collect code that helps in theming with a configuration

  - Create a module for the same. example collect code that helps you in theming a form and make a module.
- If template.php is so large, separate out the theme override functions in to separate .inc file  and include in template.php

  - Ex: theme related to layout or blocks as blocks_theme.inc

> Alternatively can this be split up into custom modules? And if so how can I get access to the $vars or $variables (page variables) that I need?

The module you design need to serve the purpose of theming. `$vars` should not be passed as such. But instead try to pass the required variables to the functions and get the themed output.